# Connecting to a .NET Core Web API - Unable to connect to remote server

Tags: c#, wpf, web, asp.net-core

I am trying to make a call from my WPF project to an API that I created in ASP.NET Core. When the call is made to the Web API end point, it is returning an error: *Unable to connect to the remote server* with the inner error being *SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.*

This is all being done on the localhost.

The code that is creating this call is(the second line throws the exception):

```
string RequestUri = "api/Class/GetEverythingDue";
HttpResponseMessage response = await myClient.GetAsync(RequestUri);
```

With myClient being an HttpClient that I configured like so:

```
this.myClient = new HttpClient();
        myClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56030/");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

I realize there are several questions with similar problems, I just haven't seen any yet that have to do with .NET Core. I just wanted to make sure that the problem wasn't due to using WPF and .NET Core together and it was due to them being incompatible.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if WPF and .NET Core communicate via http - then is compatible with every platform. Use a http snifer to define source of the problem, as long as your server can be reached via browser.

Comment: Is your web API app listening on port 56030?

Comment: I'm not 100 percent sure, how would I go about checking that?

Comment: Are you running the web API from IIS? Did you start it by Debugging in Visual Studio? How did you get that port number? Make sure the process that service the WEB API is running on your local machine.

Comment: To check whether there is a process listening on that port your local machine, you can try to run "netstat -an" in command prompt and check to see if there is an entry with that port number. You can also try to browse to that url (http://localhost:56030/) from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

The exception usually means either the firewall is stopping you or the remote server is not listening to the port. An error with your code wouldn't throw such an exception unless you closed the connection and then tried to access it.